# Find All Possible Outcomes of all Matches in a Football Tournament

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

I am working on a problem statement, where I need to return a list of all the possible combinations of outcomes in Football tournaments.

Let us assume the result of a match can be 1 - The first team won, 0 - the second team won

```
public ArrayList<Result> calculate(List<Matches> list){

    if(list.size == 0){
    return;
  } else {
    Match M = list.get(0);
    list.remove(0); 
    calculate(list);

  }
 }
```

I am trying to use a recursive approach.

**The output should be a list of all the possible outcomes of all the matches. That means if there are total 4 matches to be played then total all the possible combinations of outcomes in those four matched**

Comment: And what is your question? Will you add more details? :)  Btw, are you going to count draws?

Comment: For now, I am not considering the draws

Comment: Unfortunately, writing in bold does not make your question clearer.  How do you define your Match and Result classes?  Have you elaborated at least a simplest case, when only 1 Match is provided - should you return result of this given match, or _all_ possible results of the given match?  What do you expect to see when 2 matches is provided?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on your question, but if you're trying to return a list using a recursive approach, the general idea is:

```
public ArrayList<Result> calculate(List<Matches> list){

  if(list.size == 0){
    return new ArrayList<Result>();
  } else {
    Match m1 = list.get(0);
    list.remove(0); // If you want to include a team against itself, move this to after the for loop
    ArrayList<Result> res = new ArrayList<Result>();
    for(Match m2 : list){
      //I'm not sure how you're comparing matches, but just as an example:
      res.add(m1.compare(m2));
    }
    return res.addAll(calculate(list));
  }
}
```

Here we're taking the top match from the list, and comparing it against all other matches in the list before recursively calling on the remainder. I'm really not sure what exactly your question is, as it's not very clearly worded, but I'm hoping this helps at least.